# How to compile and link sqlite3 in a C++ program

Tags: c++, eclipse, sqlite

I get the following response when I try to compile and link sqlite3 in a C++ program.
I use Eclipse Mars for C++

> g++ "-LC:\Sqlite\sqlite3.h" -o Stryktips.exe "src\Stryktips.o" "-lC:\Sqlite\sqlite3.h"
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../.
>   ./../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lC:\Sqlite\sqlite3.h
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Sqlite\sqlite3.h` is a *header file*. And as such you should `#include` it, not link with it. You should link with a file ending with `.lib` or `.a`

And the `-L` option is to add a *directory* path, not a file.

So your linker command like should look something like this:

```
g++ -o Stryktips.exe "src\Stryktips.o" -LC:\Sqlite -lsqlite
```

That will tell the linker that libraries can be found in the `C:\Sqlite` *directory*, and that it should link with the `sqlite` library.